# Node.js - server "ISO" time vs unix time causes difference

Tags: node.js, timezone, momentjs

In the past, using unix time - which by definition is from the perspective of UTC - had never caused a discrepancy when parsing and/or translating times between servers.  However, I'm experiencing rather unexpected behavior, which I can't seem to debug for the life of me.

**THIS IS IN FACT PRODUCED AND EXPECTED ON BOTH SERVERS**

`let present = moment('2018.09.20', 'YYYY.MM.DD').tz('America/Toronto').toISOString()`

--> `'2018-09-20T04:00:00.000Z'`

`let utc_present = moment('2018.09.20', 'YYYY.MM.DD').tz('UTC').toISOString()`
--> `'2018-09-20T04:00:00.000Z'`

**UNEXPECTED BEHAVIOR WITH UNIX TIME**

However... when if I were to calculate unix time on the server, using the exact same date input, I get `1537401600000` instead of the expected `1537416000000`, which is **exactly** 4 hours off.  I suppose something might be off with server time, but I was under the impression that explicitly converting to unix solves this.

Printing the unix equivalent below for reference, taken from one of the severs.

`let unix_present = moment('2018.09.20', 'YYYY.MM.DD').tz('America/Toronto').unix()*1000`

--> `1537416000000`

`let unix_present = moment('2018.09.20', 'YYYY.MM.DD').tz('UTC').unix()*1000`

--> `1537416000000`

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- In all of the cases you described, `moment('2018.09.20', 'YYYY.MM.DD')` parses the date as midnight in your *local* time zone.  Thus, you will get different results depending on what time zone you are running the code in.
- In all of the cases, you are using `.tz('some zone')`, which is for *converting* a moment to a particular zone.  Since you are subsequently asking for the Unix time (which is in UTC as you stated), then the time zone conversion has no effect on the output.
- You don't need to do `.unix()*1000`, you can just do `.valueOf()` - as milliseconds are tracked internally already.

If you meant midnight of that date in Toronto, then:

```
moment.tz('2018.09.20', 'YYYY.MM.DD', 'America/Toronto').valueOf() //=> 1537416000000
```

If you meant midnight of that date in UTC, then you don't need moment-timezone, just:

```
moment.utc('2018.09.20', 'YYYY.MM.DD').valueOf()  //=> 1537401600000
```

Comment: This is key: "`moment('2018.09.20', 'YYYY.MM.DD')` parses the date as midnight in your local time zone...." - thanks!  I would have expected that leaving that out would default to UTC, similar to `new Date()`.  I'll send a PR to add this to the docs.

Comment: It's in the docs.  There's also a section on parsing in the "guides" section at the top.

Comment: I added a note to the parsing section, as the existing mentions are further down.

Also, having tried this on the server, explicitly passing in`'America/Toronto'` still results in the unexpected behavior mentioned above.  However, it did work once I explicitly `setDefault`.